Request become very long when using "GROUP BY"
I try to optimize my website and found some SQL queries which are long (3-4 seconds), when I created the site years ago, databases was empty so I thought SQL request was good, but now I have 100,000 rows it's very slow.
This is the request:
SELECT c.*, p.*, COUNT(o.OrderID) as nb_total 
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN products p on o.OrderProductID = p.ProductID 
INNER JOIN categories c on c.CategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID 
WHERE p.deleted = 0 
GROUP BY o.OrderProductID 
ORDER BY nb_total DESC 
LIMIT 10

I have 3 distinct tables:

orders
products
categories

This request is to find the 10 more ordered product, and get some data from the category (color, icon), the product (name, thumbnail) and count the orders to order by this.
I have indexes on ProductCategoryID, CategoryID and OrderProductID.
Can you please explain me why without the GROUP BY the request takes 0.00005s and with the group by it take 3 seconds? And how can I repair this?

EXPLAIN of the query? Exact database structure?

@HonkderHase https://ibb.co/M98RL7P

When creating a database you typically also created indexes. In order to get a good answer here, you need to specify your database structure like Honk suggests.
You can also run each SQL query with the word explain infront, and that will show you some stats. What you want to see is if there is any full table scans. That means that the query will scale linearly with the size of your table.

2 possible keys on products, but neither is used. Order by count is not able to use an index (hence "filesort" and "temporary"). Compare to the EXPLAIN of the query without GROUP BY (I bet it uses a proper index then..)

Oh, and btw: Strictly spoken, the whole query with GROUP BY is invalid - you may only select grouped fields or aggregate :)

@HonkderHase the group by invalid is true for every other database, for mysql, it has a configuration that allows this abomination :facepalm:

The browser sends a request to the web site, but the web site code runs a query (not a request) on the MySQL server. The MySQL has a database with multiple tables. It can also have multiple databases, but that's a different level.  This may seem pedantic, but you're a programmer, trying to communicate with a computer... and computers are ultimate in pedantry. So precision in your terms like this is important.

@JorgeCampos "abomination" I couldn't have put it better. The formal ANSI spec allows for "cheating" with GROUP BY if the database can infer a "functional dependency", but most DBs still don't support that and a SELECT table.* should never satisfy it unless you're grouping by the primary key, in which case why even bother with a GROUP BY?

@JorgeCampos SQLite also allows non-deterministic columns in a grouping query. But your right that the SQL standard and every other SQL implementation disallows it. MySQL also disallows it by default in current versions.

MySQL only allows it under the conditions written in the docs MySQL Handling of GROUP BY


now I have 100,000 rows it's very slow.

You're selecting c.* and p.*... every column in the table. Then, you're sending all this data across the wire from the database server to your application.
Odds are, you only need a few of those columns... so only select the columns you need. This will greatly reduce the data transfer burden, helpings things go faster. I know you only want 10 rows for this query, so it's not a complete fix, but it's a starting place.
Additionally, it's possible this is forcing MySQL to load more data into the working set for the query than it might otherwise... far beyond just the final 10 rows, consuming a LOT more memory than is needed.
More probably, the final solution will be setting an index for this query. But since we can't see any of your index definitions this is as much as we can do for you at the moment, and it's something you should do anyway.
